# Laravel passing variable to wherehas query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to pass variable to wherehas query in laravel.. but getting an error of undefined variable,
In method, if has nature then go where has natures equal to $catname...
in line no. 4

```
public function Products($catname,Request $request)     //Product Category Pages
{
    $natures = Nature::where('nature_slug', '=', $catname)
                    ->first();
    if($natures)
    {   //Where Clause Based On Products Nature
        //dd($catname);
        $maxproductscost = Product::selectRaw('MAX(ABS(price)) AS HighestPrice')
                                ->whereHas('natures', function($q) use ($catname)
                                    {
                                        $q->where('nature_slug', '=', $catname);
                                    })
                                ->first();
        $maxproductscost = ceiling($maxproductscost->HighestPrice, 100);
        /*End - GEt Maximum cost of product*/
        if($request->range){
            $range = $request->range;
            $pieces = explode(" ", $range);
            $rangestart = $pieces['1'];
            $rangeend = $pieces['4'];
        }
        $firstslidervalue = $request->range ? $rangestart : 0;
        $secondslidervalue = $request->range ? $rangeend : $maxproductscost;
        $sorting = $request->sorting ? $request->sorting : '';

        $products = Product::whereHas('natures', function($q)
            {
                $q->where('nature_slug', '=', $catname);

            });
        
    }
    else
    {
        //Where Clause Based On Products Nature is General
        /*GEt Maximum cost of product*/
        $maxproductscost = Product::selectRaw('MAX(ABS(price)) AS HighestPrice')
                                ->where('ptype', '=', $catname)
                                ->whereHas('natures', function($q)
                                    {
                                        $q->where('nature_slug', '=', 'general');
                                    })
                                ->first();
        $maxproductscost = ceiling($maxproductscost->HighestPrice, 100);
        /*End - GEt Maximum cost of product*/
        if($request->range){
            $range = $request->range;
            $pieces = explode(" ", $range);
            $rangestart = $pieces['1'];
            $rangeend = $pieces['4'];
        }
        $firstslidervalue = $request->range ? $rangestart : 0;
        $secondslidervalue = $request->range ? $rangeend : $maxproductscost;
        $sorting = $request->sorting ? $request->sorting : '';

        $products = Product::where('ptype', '=', $catname)
                        ->whereHas('natures', function($q)
            {
                $q->where('nature_slug', '=', 'general');

            });
    }

    if($request->range){
        $products->whereBetween('price', [$rangestart, $rangeend]);
    }
    if($sorting)
    {
        if($sorting == 'low')
        {
            $products->orderByRaw('(ABS(stock) > 0) desc, (case when ABS(stock) > 0 then ABS(price) end) asc, (case when ABS(stock) = 0 then ABS(price) end) asc ');
        } else
        {
            $products->orderByRaw('(ABS(stock) > 0) desc, (case when ABS(stock) > 0 then ABS(price) end) DESC, (case when ABS(stock) = 0 then ABS(price) end) DESC ');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $products->orderByRaw('(ABS(stock) > 0) desc, (case when ABS(stock) > 0 then id end) DESC, (case when ABS(stock) = 0 then id end) DESC ');
    }
    
        
    $products = $products->paginate(12);

    $user = Auth::user();               
    return view('products',compact('user','catname','products','maxproductscost','firstslidervalue','secondslidervalue','sorting'));
}
```

[image]

Comment: `$catname = abc;` should be `$catname = 'abc';`

Comment: its dynamic variable

Comment: its undefined variable

Comment: This should work fine. Show us the full code

Comment: checkout the above code...i had updated the code..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To pass a variable to closure you have to use the use() function

```
$products = Product::whereHas('natures', function($q) use($catname)
        {
            $q->where('nature_slug', '=', $catname);

        });
```

Comment: You havent done this under this statement

    `$sorting = $request->sorting ? $request->sorting : '';`

Comment: You have the whereHas thing called twice in the code. You have used the use() function 1st time and not the 2nd time

Comment: why do i need ternary operator as i am passing it from function itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want provide string in variable, use this code

```
$catname = 'abc';
```

or declare abc constant

```
const abc = 123;
```

Comment: its dynamic variable

Comment: I mean you code $catname = abc; is wrong. did you declared abc constant?